Object within a class itself and function invocations
Okay, so I'm performing cellular updates on a grid representing an ocean. I have a method called update_grid() that needs to create a copy of the current Ocean object and use this.grid's data and update temp_grid cells so that we avoid data dependency in different time steps:
/**
         * @brief updates the grid
         * @details First, generates a temporary copy of the current grid with all empty values
         *          Second, performs all updates on the copy grid while using data from old grid to avoid data dependency.
         *          Third, replaces the old grid with the new grid.
         */
        void update_grid() {
            // make a temporary Ocean object, a copied version of current object calling this function.
            Ocean temp_ocean(*this);
            
            // Iterate over this temp_ocean:
            for (int i = 0; i < temp_ocean.num_rows; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < temp_ocean.num_cols; ++j) {
                    // skip empty cells
                    if (temp_ocean.get_cell(i, j) == Occupy::Empty) { continue; }
                    // retrieve cell state from current grid:
                    Occupy curr_obj = get_cell(i, j);
                    // perform movement based on the object type
                    switch(curr_obj) {
                        // when Turtle
                        case Occupy::Turtle:
                            temp_ocean.turtle_move(i, j);
                            break;
                        // when Trash
                        case Occupy::Trash:
                            temp_ocean.trash_move(i, j);
                            break;
                        // when  Ship
                        case Occupy::Ship:
                            temp_ocean.ship_move(i, j);
                            break;
                        // default:
                        default: break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // replace the original Ocean object with the temp one:
            *this = temp_ocean;
        };

This is my current draft. I'll also paste other functions that are used.
            void turtle_move (int i, int j) {
            // use random_direction () function with default prob of 1 / 9.
            move(i, j, Occupy::Turtle, random_direction());
        };

and finally, getter and setter functions:
        /**
    * @brief setter for a specific cell
    * @param i index of row, starting at 0
    * @param j index of column, starting at 0
    * @param value value to update that cell
    */
    void set_cell(int i, int j, Ocean::Occupy value) {
        grid.at(i * num_cols + j) = static_cast<int>(value);
    }
    /**
    * @brief getter for a specific cell
    * @param i index of row, starting at 0
    * @param j index of column, starting at 0
    * @return cell state in Occupy enum;
    */
    Ocean::Occupy get_cell(int i, int j) {
        return static_cast<Ocean::Occupy>(grid.at(i * num_cols + j));
    }

My Question is within my update_grid(), i'm using this class methods directly at temp_ocean object and not "this." Thus, will all the function invocation directly change the status of temp_ocean members or will they change the current object's members?
For example, within update_grid() it uses turtle_move(). Will that turtle_move() act on temp_grid or this.grid?
By the way, all the methods are under class Ocean.
The main() would look something like this:
int main() {
   Ocean ocean{// set up constructor};
   ocean.update_grid();
   return 0;
}

Should I use this-> keyword in all of my methods?

This question desperately calls for a minimal example. Drop everything you intend to do with your code. Create one object, then create your copy, then invoke one function that uses "this class methods directly" (whatever that means). It should be under a dozen lines.

When you call temp_ocean.function() it will operate on temp_oceans member variables. It's not obvious why you make the copy though.

At a guess, your minimized class should be along the lines of struct Ocean { void update_grid() { Ocean temp_ocean(*this); [The function call you are asking about] }
void foo() {} }; (See [mre].)

@JaMiT Sorry i significantly reduced the OG post. and amended the question

@TedLyngmo Oh gotcha. Would that be true for any function inside the originally invoked function? for example, in my case, turtle_move() is inside update_grid(). Would both be acting on temp_ocean instead of *this? thank you!

@TedLyngmo I need to make a copy and making updates on that copy instead of the original object because of data dependency. i need to use current state (time = t0) to update ocean at time = t1. if i don't make copy, cells at time = t1 depdends on  previously updated values at time = t1... if that makes sense...

@roundofferror If you don't name the instance, it will use this->. So, just update_grid() will not act on temp_ocean but *this.

@TedLyngmo ohhh... so whenever i name the instance, it acts on the instance...then i need to go ahead and change the other functions so that it names the instance...right

@roundofferror "i significantly reduced the OG post" -- I acknowledge that this was significant progress in the right direction, but it is not enough. For example, why do you need to "Iterate over this temp_ocean" in order to demonstrate "using this class methods directly at temp_ocean object and not 'this.'"? As I mentioned earlier, update_grid likely should have no more than two lines: one to define temp_ocean and one to demonstrate what you mean by "using this class methods directly at temp_ocean object".
